# Performance of Web Database against new standard service tier

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have sql azure database. Currently I'm using the "Web" SQL database since my DB was small ie about 300mb and the maximum size is 5GB. I came to know that the Web service tiers will be retired in September 2015 i have restored my my Live DB as a "Standard" s0 which has a maximum size of 2 GB. But what i noticed is the performance with the new standard type database is poor when compared to the retired web edition. Say for instance it used to take like 40 seconds to delete 60 thousand records in the Web edition and it is now taking two minutes to 3 minutes with the new standard type. Have any one  experienced this kind of thing or its just me ?

Please give me your suggestions

Comment: See the DBA Stack Exchange. This has happened before.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue; I migrated sql 2008 to Azure web; got a performance hit; then switched from web to S0; got another hit. I think im now at s1

I figured it was probably missing indexes; but with the ability to Trace + tune gone with azure, I had to do things a bit more manually.

First, look at this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394114.aspx you want to be able to get to the part where you can get the long running queries.

Then, with each long running query; you will want to execute the execution plan. To view a query’s execution plan, we need to explicitly include it before executing the query. Right-Click the query window and select Include Actual Execution Plan.

If this does not help you then you need to do more work; what you will want to do is export the database (it comes out as a bacpac file) to sql 2012 (Right click on the Connection > Databases node and select "Import Data-tier application...") on a local server somwhere (I used an Azure VM); then hookup an application/website to this, enable query analyzer., and tune it the old way., this will reveal all the non-clustered indexes that magically disappeared... once you add those to your sql azure db, you will get performance back.

Sure you could just increase your standard tier., but this can get expensive., its better to tune and find out where things went wrong...